# How to use RODFT00 and REDFT00

Tags: fourier-analysis, fftw

I have some difficulty in implementing `RODFT00` and `REDFT00`. I want to use them for fluid simulations.

I would really appreciate some help with my following problems:

1. I have read the documentation
   (http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Real-even_002fodd-DFTs-_0028cosine_002fsine-transforms_0029.html#Real-even_002fodd-DFTs-_0028cosine_002fsine-transforms_0029)
   and have been unable to understand

`The r2r kinds for the various REDFT and RODFT types supported by FFTW, along with the boundary conditions at both ends of the input array (n real numbers in[j=0..n-1]), are:`

`FFTW_REDFT00 (DCT-I): even around j=0 and even around j=n-1.`
`FFTW_RODFT00 (DST-I): odd around j=-1 and odd around j=n.`

`Note that these symmetries apply to the “logical” array being transformed; there are no constraints on your physical input data.`

What does it explains about the implementation of cosine and sine transforms?

2. Since I want to obtain the differentiation using the transforms. How should I arrange the wavenumbers to multiply with the matrix in both the cases??